# Invalid selector error when trying to export webtable to excel

Tags: java, excel, selenium, webdriver, apache-poi

**Error is:** 
The given selector table[class='stats_table data_grid'] tbody tr [0] td [0] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

**Observation:**
I have checked the cssSelector without ["+r+"] and ["+c+"] and it is valid.
So the error is coming from adding ["+r+"] and ["+c+"], and I am unable to mitigate it. My overall goal is to take data from webtable from mlb.com/stats and 
enter it into an excel sheet. Almost 99 percent of the code is working fine, 
except for the invalid cssSelector issue.

**My code is:**

```
package automate;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class MLBtoXL   {


    static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Navigate to mlb.com/stats
        driver.navigate().to("http://goo.gl/El1PIV");

        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
                ("table[class='stats_table data_grid']"));

        List<WebElement> irow = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        int iRowCount = irow.size();

        List<WebElement> icol = table.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        int iColCount = icol.size();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream
                ("/Users/HARSHENDU/Desktop/MLBtoXL.xlsx");

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet ws = wb.createSheet("Team Stats");

        for(int r=0; r<=iRowCount; r++) {
            XSSFRow excelrow = ws.createRow(r);
            for(int c=0; c<iColCount; c++) {


 // Invalid selector exception coming up for the following cssSelector.
                WebElement cellval = driver.findElement
 (By.cssSelector("table[class='stats_table data_grid'] tbody tr ["+r+"] td ["+c+"]"));
                String cellcontent = cellval.getText();
                XSSFCell excelcell = excelrow.createCell(c);
                excelcell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                excelcell.setCellValue(cellcontent);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    fos.flush();
    wb.write(fos);
    fos.close();

        end();

    }

    public static void end() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the table html?

Comment: Thank you Guy for helping me. Here's the HTML

Comment: html is too long to be pasted here, and I am not seeing anyway of attaching it as a file. However it is the html from the following link: http://goo.gl/El1PIV

Comment: I checked the xpath with eval button in firepath and it shows the xpath being valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using an XPath would solve your issue:

```
WebElement cellval = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//table[@class='stats_table data_grid']/tbody/tr["+r+"]/td["+c+"]"));
```

Comment: Hi Ben, Thank you for the idea, , getting a new error now as follows:  

Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table[@class='stats_table data_grid']/tbody/tr[1]/td[33]"}

Comment: So now it's reading the whole table from index 1 to 33, but unable to find the element. very puzzling.

Comment: I checked the xpath with eval button in firepath and it shows the xpath being valid

Comment: @H1b1 if your table has multiple classes then you will need to do something like `[contains(@class, 'stats_table')]` instead of an exact check

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `index` attribute. Try

```
WebElement cellval = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table[class='stats_table data_grid'] tbody tr[index="+r+"] td[index="+c+"]");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but error is still the same. now it's showing index 1 as issue:

The given selector table[class='stats_table data_grid'] tbody tr [1] td [1] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: This time I did what you have suggested, but used an xpath instead of cssSelector and I get the following error:

Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table[@class='stats_table data_grid']/tbody/tr[1]/td[33]"}

So now it's reading all indexes from 1 till 33, so your idea worked, however still can't find the element.

Comment: I checked the xpath with eval button in firepath and it shows the xpath being valid